# How to cluster new data using cluster centers generated by kmeans

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have got some cluster centers using `kmeans` in Matlab.

Now there are some new data points, I don't want to use `for` loop to compare the distance between every data points and cluster centers, because it's too slow.

So how should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this.
If your new points are stored in **coord** with rows as points and columns as coordinates, and your cluster means are similarly stored in **means**, and you want to know which cluster each point is closest to (in ).
Then:

```
% compute distance
d2 = repmat(sum(coord.^2,2),1,size(means,1)) + repmat(sum(means.^2,2)',size(coord,1),1) - 2*coord*means';
% Assign to nearest cluster
[~, assigns] = min(d2,[],2);
```

Comment: or maybe more pedagogically with bsxfun: bsxfun(@plus,sum(coord.^2,2),sum(means.^2,2)') - 2*coord*means'

Answer (score 1):

Try to use matlab knnsearch(X,Y) were X is the matrix that represent the kmeans centers and Y is the set of new data points.

look http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html